# How to make Mockito throw an exception when a mock is called with non-defined parameters?

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible to throw an exception whenever a mock is called with non-predefined arguments? There is `Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS`, but it's not really what I need, since it doesn't work if `null` is legitimate return value, which doesn't lead to `NullPointerException`, but rather to errors later on.

Edit: some background. So, in Mockito when you define a mock, you specify the return values for each call like this:

```
when(myMock.someMethod(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(returnValue);
```

When `myMock.someMethod` is called with arguments, for which I didn't give a return value in the test, it just returns `null`. I would like to configure it to crash right away and tell me that I forgot to define the return value for some combination of parameters.

Edit 2: There were suggestions to provide a custom `defaultAnswer` that would throw exceptions when called. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The default answers' `answer()` method is called even if a mock is present. Here's a sample:

```
public class Test {
  public static class Adder {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  }

  public static final Answer<Object> THROW_ON_UNDEFINED_ARGS = new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          String.format("Calling a mock with undefined arguments: %s %s",
              invocation.getMethod(),
              Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments())));
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Adder adderMock = mock(Adder.class, THROW_ON_UNDEFINED_ARGS);
    when(adderMock.add(2, 3)).thenReturn(5);
    System.out.println(adderMock.add(2, 3));
  }
}
```

The exception is thrown even though `adderMock.add(2, 3)` is defined.

Comment: "Is it possible to throw an exception whenever a mock is called with non-predefined arguments?" - What does it exactly mean? You want to simulate throwing an exception if some parameters are passed? What non-prefedined arguments means?

Comment: So, in Mockito you define the return values for mocks like this: `when(myMock.someMethod(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(result)`. If `myMock.someMethod` is called with some other arguments, it returns null. I want it to fail right away and tell me, that mock was called with arguments, for which I didn't define return value.

Answer (score 23):

You could provide a default `Answer` in the construction of your mock that always throws an exception. Then every call that is stubbed will act like usual. Everything outside those paths will throw an exception. Something like this:

```
final String arg = "some arg";
Collection<Object> object = mock(Collection.class, new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot invoke " + invocation.getMethod() +
                                    " with " + Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));
    }
});
doReturn(true).when(object).add(arg);

object.add(arg); // Goes ok
object.add("azertyuiop"); // Throws the exception
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this `Answer` can be reused and specified as `@Mock(answer = thisAnswer)`. I wonder why this is not one of the choices in `mockito.Answers` enum.

Comment: You can use existing class `org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.ThrowsException`

Comment: I was wrong about @Mock BTW. It only accepts values of the enum `Answers`, not an arbitrary `Answer`.

Comment: @OlegEterevsky You'll need to create the mock manually as shown above instead of relying on the annotation.

Comment: Turns out, this solution doesn't work: Mockito calls the defaultAnswer even if it does have a mock answer, so exception happens in any case. Here's a sample: http://pastebin.com/aa43EwBs

Comment: @OlegEterevsky OK, the problems actually comes from when you are trying to stub the method. Either use the `doReturn().when(mock).method()` construction, or turn a flag on/off when creating your stubs and use that flag in your `Answer`. See my update above.

Answer (score 7):

Just point another way you can do that, using `thenAnswer`:

```
when(myMock.someMethod(anyString(), anyString())).
            thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
               @Override
               public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                  Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                  String arg1 = (String) args[0];
                  String arg2 = (String) args[1];

                  if ("arg1".equals(arg1) && "arg2".equals(arg2)) return "someValue";

                  throw new Exception();
               }
            });

      myMock.someMethod("arg1", "arg2"); // Returns "someValue"
      myMock.someMethod("xxx", "yyy");   // Throws Exception
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

First, a bit of "good engineering" mumble - why would you like to do this? Mockito tries to 'promote' BDD style - you set up (mock) your calls, you execute the code and verify interactions were exactly as you expected rather then 'it didn't called anything else' - Do you try to do something described in [Finding irrelevant invocation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#finding_redundant_invocations)?
Generally if I want to mock all the cases, but one - this makes my ask myself whether my tests are really OK.

Anyway, to the topic :)

In Mockito, you can define multiple `when`s with different values, like

```
class Foo {
   public String bar(int a) {
       return "bar = " + a;
   }
}

Mockito.when(task.bar(Matchers.anyInt())).thenReturn("L")
Mockito.when(task.bar(3)).thenThrow(new IllegalAccessError())

task.bar(4); // returns "L" 
task.bar(3); //throws IllegalAccessError
```

Notice that the order of `when`s DOES matter. The rules are processed in reversed order (or rather overrides the actual matchers). 
In my code we first mock for anyInt, then for 3 - which works. If you reverse it - both calls to `bar()` will return 'L'.

Comment: I have no intentions to check that the tested method doesn't call something. I just want to quickly find the calls in the mock that I didn't specify. RETURNS_SMART_NULLS helps, but it doesn't work for methods for which null is a legal return value. Right now I am debuging just such a problem. The test fails because of an incorrect result. I suspect that it's because some mock method returned null instead of the correct value.

Comment: You can just print all interactions using `mock(Foo.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());` - for the sake of debugging. 
Moreover, when you do `verify` in the test, Mockito will print all interactions with the given object if the verification fails

Comment: Thanks, logging might help.

Comment: 'you set up (mock) your calls, you execute the code and verify interactions were exactly as you expected'... Why is throwing an exception instead of returning null antithetical to this? If the setup is incorrect or the implementation changes to require a different setup, shouldn't that be accounted for and made explicit instead of just returning null? Having all interactions make explicit changes and more explicit when there is a regression.